# How to use `hg amend` with HgGit to avoid `unknown revision` errors

Tags: git, mercurial, rebase, mercurial-extension, mercurial-amend

Whenever I use `hg amend` or other commands that change history (for example `hg rebase -s ... -d ...`), certain commands, including `hg push` start to fail with `abort: unknown revision` error:

```
$ hg push -B my-branch
pushing to git+ssh://git@github.com:...
searching for changes
abort: unknown revision 'xxxxx'!
```

Answer (score 1):

When using [`hg amend`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#id32) or other [history-altering commands](https://book.mercurial-scm.org/read/changing-history.html) in Mercurial (Hg), especially when working with the [HgGit extension](https://wiki.mercurial-scm.org/HgGit) to interact with Git repositories, you might encounter `abort: unknown revision 'xxxxx'!` errors: often, this is because these operations rewrite history, which can confuse the mapping between Mercurial changesets and Git commits.

To avoid this issue, follow these steps when you need to amend a commit or rebase:

- use `hg commit --amend` carefully: Make sure you only amend commits that have not been pushed to a Git repository. Amending already pushed commits can create discrepancies between your local repository and the remote Git repository.
- Push changes immediately after amending: If you are amending a commit that is part of a series of commits not yet pushed to the remote Git repository, push your changes immediately after amending to minimize discrepancies.
- Recreate the mapping: If you have already encountered the `unknown revision` error, you may need to recreate the mapping between your Mercurial repository and the Git repository. That can involve pulling from the Git repository again, or using `hg strip` to remove the problematic commits locally and then re-applying your changes.

If you are aware of the implications and are certain that no other users will be affected (for example, in a personal project), you could use [`hg push --force`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#push) to override the remote repository. Be very cautious with this approach, as it can lead to lost work for others.

```
# Option 1: Force push (caution)
$ hg push -B my-branch --force

# Option 2: Fix the mapping (more complex, might involve pulling and merging)
```

You can also test [schacon/hg-git/issues/298](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/issues/298#issuecomment-205149099)

> A Problem can be solved by follow command:
>
> ```
> hg rebase -b --keepbranch
> ```
>
> or add in `.hgrc`
>
> ```
> [default]
>   rebase= --keepbranch
> ```